# SPARQL - Query based on some property

Tags: sparql, jena, owl, protege

I want to get all the pizza names which has cheese toppings but the result shows (_:b0) which is kind of an owl restriction following is my query

```sql
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
SELECT ?X WHERE {
    ?X rdfs:subClassOf* [
        owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping ;
        owl:someValuesFrom pizza:CheeseTopping
    ]
}
```

using Pizza ontology from stanford

Comment: That's the wrong query. Look at the data and pick on pizza and try to match the data. For example `CheesyPizza`, look at the data. It won't match without reasoning enabled. Moreover, your query won't return results with a topping defined as subclass of `CheeseTopping`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works (Without reasoning enabled)

```
 PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
 SELECT ?X ?topping WHERE {
     ?X rdfs:subClassOf ?Y .  
     ?Y owl:someValuesFrom ?topping .
     ?topping rdfs:subClassOf* pizza:CheeseTopping
 } 
 ORDER BY ?X
```

Some are listed more than once as they could contain more than one CheeseTopping. To remove duplicates:

```
 PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
 SELECT DISTINCT ?X WHERE {
        ?X rdfs:subClassOf ?Y .  
        ?Y owl:someValuesFrom ?topping .
        ?topping rdfs:subClassOf* pizza:CheeseTopping
 }
 ORDER BY ?X
```

This works if you enable a reasoner:

```
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?X WHERE {
    ?X rdfs:subClassOf pizza:CheeseyPizza
}
```

Ref:
Used the pizza ontology from here: http://protege.stanford.edu/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl

Answer (score 1):

That query works but is really complex and might be incomplete because some pizzas use complex OWL constructs:

```sql
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?pizza WHERE {

  {
    ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf* pizza:Pizza .
    ?pizza owl:equivalentClass|rdfs:subClassOf [
      rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
      owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping ;
               owl:someValuesFrom/rdfs:subClassOf* pizza:CheeseTopping 
      ]

   } UNION {
    ?pizza  owl:equivalentClass  _:b0 .
    _:b0    rdf:type             owl:Class ;
            owl:intersectionOf   _:b1 .
    _:b1 (rdf:rest)*/rdf:first ?otherClass.
     ?otherClass rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
               owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping ;
               owl:someValuesFrom/rdfs:subClassOf* pizza:CheeseTopping 


   }
}
```